My cronjob to remove old data with 2 filters fails to match 1 of the filters
I am trying to create a cronjob to remove old directories (and everything within them) but skip one entire directory and any directory that ends in .save. I have tried a variety of the following find/rm job but it deletes the .save dirs.  It does leave the blist/ directory intact.  I've used !, -not, -prune, with and without -depth, reversed the order of blist and .save, replaced -name with -path before ".save", etc...
Ubuntu 24.04
I'm testing so I'm just looking for anything older than 1 minute for now.
find test_dir/store/tmp/ -depth -type d \( ! -name "*.save" -o ! -path test_dir/store/tmp/blist \) -mmin +1 -exec rm -rf {} 2>/dev/null \;
Just focusing on the *.save part, the following command will find all the *.save directories I expect.
usr@dev9:~$ find test_dir/store/tmp/ -type d \( -name "*.save" \) -mmin +1
test_dir/store/tmp/proj3/NX3.save

But this command removes everything older than 1 minute including all *.save directories. Using '-not' instead of '!' behaves the same.
usr@dev9:~$ ls -l test_dir/store/tmp/proj3/
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 3 usr usr 4096 Nov 20 08:51 NX1
drwxrwxr-x 3 usr usr 4096 Nov 20 08:51 NX2
drwxrwxr-x 3 usr usr 4096 Nov 20 08:51 NX3
drwxrwxr-x 3 usr usr 4096 Nov 20 08:51 NX3.save
drwxrwxr-x 3 usr usr 4096 Nov 20 08:51 NX4
usr@dev9:~$ find test_dir/store/tmp/ -type d \( ! -name "*.save" \) -mmin +1  -exec rm -rf {} 2>/dev/null \;
usr@dev9:~$ ls -l test_dir/store/tmp/proj3/
ls: cannot access 'test_dir/store/tmp/proj3/': No such file or directory

Any help is appreciated.
This is a summary of my directory structure.
test_dir
└── store
    └── tmp
        ├── blist
        ├── proj1
        ├── proj2
        └── proj3
            ├── NX1
            │   └── bdata
            ├── NX2
            │   └── bdata
            ├── NX3
            │   └── bdata
            ├── NX3.save
            │   └── bdata
            └── NX4
                └── bdata


This may be better asked on The Unix/Linux network site. I don't know bash so I can't tell if this is sufficiently programming-related or not with regard to Bash, but typically questions about cron jobs are not 'over the threshold' in that regard.

Ok. Will put future cron job questions over there.

It looks like your command is matching on and removing the parent directories.
-mindepth might be the flag you're looking for. From man find
       -mindepth levels
          Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than
          levels (a non-negative integer).  Using -mindepth 1 means
          process all files except the starting-points.

Copying your directory structure I used this command which I think will give you the result you're looking for (or close to it).
find test_dir/store/tmp/ -mindepth 3 -type d \( -name "*.save" \)

Yes, that looks like it was my biggest problem, removing the parent directories.  Thanks!  I had to make one other change after implementing the -mindepth.  Everything under my .save directories was being deleted.  I'm still doing a bit of testing but it looks like this is my final command that preserves .save dirs and everything under them and the blist dir.
find test_dir/store/tmp/ -mindepth 2 -type d ( -not -path test_dir/store/tmp/blist -and ( -not -name ".save" -and -not -path "/tmp//.save/*" ) ) -mmin +1  -exec rm -rf {} 2>/dev/null ;
